# Flutter internationalization using dynamic value matches with arb file value

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-localizations

I want to get translations from locally saved .arb files. I have the below code in a loop.
So if the dynamic value matches the value in the .arb files, I get the translation.

```
 Text(Translation.of(context).!filterTitle ),
```

Unfortunately, I can't find how to do that. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After 2 days I got the answer. Hopefully will help someone.
You need to use the select feature of .arb files

```
"facetTitle": "{facetTitle, select, age_group{Age Group} product_type{Product Type} collection{Collection} gender{Gender} other {{facetTitle}}
```

and in dart file use below

```
S.of(context).facetTitle(text1)
```

text1 is the dynamic value which will match with select in .arb file.

Comment: how about a two words key like when product_type = x y for example